# What is "sub-Indo-European"?

Tags: terminology, historical-linguistics, indo-european, substrate

Apparently Leiden had a conference on "sub-Indo-European".

Google isn't very helpful, resulting in a dead link:

> Sub-Indo-European Europe: Problems, Methods and Evidence - Leiden University
> 30.08.2021 — The ERC funded EUROLITHIC project led by Guus Kroonen is organizing a workshop on the evidence for prehistoric language contact ...

The schedule [archived Jan '22](https://web.archive.org/web/20220123162306/https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/en/events/2021/08/sub-indo-european-europe-problems-methods-and-evidence) confirms that it all about sub-strates.

Another link to a paper from Journal of Language Relation 2013 shows the term set in scare quotes:

> Although there is no single genetic marker that could be definitively linked with all Indo-Europeans, there could be sets of genetic markers, partially linked with some Indo-European
> branches. The more genetic markers we take into consideration, the higher are the chances that
> such “sub-Indo-European” markers might be identified

> [*Genetics of Indo-European populations: the past, the future*. O Balanovsky (2013)]

Substrata may be implied, tl;dr.

That's about it. What is this?

Comment: Marketing. Every conference needs a catchy name, and conference organisers can get very creative in this respect.

Comment: The paper from 2013 seems to be using it to mean "related to some subset of Indo-European"

Comment: I vaguely remember talking to Guus about this workshop a few years ago. His EUROLITHIC project was primarily about substrates and prehistoric encounters/interactions between Indo-European and pre-Indo-European languages in Europe, and that’s essentially what the workshop was about as well – so ‘sub’ = substrate there. The programme seems to bear that out. The second quote seems to be using the term ‘sub-Indo-European markers’ to refer more to ‘markers that are characteristic to specific Indo-European subgroups’ – obviously not linguistic substrates there, since it’s about genetics.

Comment: My point being, what evidence between the two am I missing? The common distinction is pre-IE for substrates in contrast to to pre-proto- for a presumed pre stage of the proto language. Since genetic subsets virtually imply linguistic substrata, sub-IE would fit, as every branch has its linguistic substrate hypotheses (e.g. an episode of exchange between Slavic and Germanic, isoglosses between Greek, Armenian and Latin, according to Warnow-Ringe-Taylor 2005, which is not pre-IE).